# nodejs sqlite issue with console.log() all rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite

I've run into a little problem with [nodejs sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite) that I can't seem to find an answer to. I have a database with a table which is the guild ID (this is for a Discord bot). I am trying to return the 2 rows inside the table (table and rows can be seen [here for reference](https://can-we.date/please/DarkgreyDegu.png)).

The problem I am having is that when I do `console.log(row.userid)`, it only returns the first row, and not the first and second. Please let me know if any more information is needed, thanks.

```
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM '${message.guild.id}'`).then(row => {
  if (!row) {
      console.log("No users found.");
  } else {
      console.log(row.userid);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch the error in `then block`, instead it will be in the `catch` block. This should work.

```
sql.all(`SELECT * FROM '${message.guild.id}'`).then(function(rows){
  rows.forEach(function (row) {
    console.log(row);
  });
}).catch(function(err){
   console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `sql.all` rather than `sql.get`. the 'get' will only return the first result in the set. following should work

```
sql.all(`SELECT * FROM '${message.guild.id}'`).then(rows => {
  rows.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row);
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: `sql.all` returns a single undefined, and `console.log(row)` returns `{ userid: '244669855998017538' }`

Comment: Gave that one a shot and logged this. I believe this is the `console.log(err);`

`[ { userid: '244669855998017538' },
  { userid: '147478852015357952' } ]`

Comment: @mononz why use a `function(err,rows)` inside `then` block? If `error` happened that will be in the catch block right?